# Is it better to pass a service as an argument in a constructor or pass it in each class method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop, object-oriented-analysis

```
from government.powerSupply import power
```

**Case 1**: Should service object be initial zed in constructor of the class and same amont of energy be available to house at all times

```
class Home(object):
    def __init__(self, rooms=4, people=2, services=None):
        self._services = services or power.Service()
        self.connectionType = 2 # MeghaWatts
        self.roomLights = {1:False, 2:False: 3: False, 4: False}

    def turnLightsOn(self, room=None, all=False):
        voltage = self._services.voltage()
        if all:
            for light, _ in self.roomLights.iteritems():
                    self.roomLights[light] = True
            return True
        else:
            if room:
                    self.roomLights[room]
                    return True
```

or

**Case 2** it should be done like this that function being called outside should have option to pass in services so different amount of power can be given to room whose light being turned on.

```
class Home(object):
    def __init__(self, rooms=4, people=2, services=None):
        self._services = services or power.Service()
        self.connectionType = 2 # MeghaWatts
        self.roomLights = {1:False, 2:False: 3: False, 4: False}

    def turnLightsOn(self, room=None, all=False, services=None):
        # in this case service can be passed from outside when call to         
        # turnLights on is made, and service can have different voltage input 
        self._services = services or self._services
        voltage = self._services.voltage()
        if all:
            for light, _ in self.roomLights.iteritems():
                    self.roomLights[light] = True
            return True
        else:
            if room:
                    self.roomLights[room]
                    return True
```

today,  I was working on updating Unittest at office and found it convenient to do the **Case 2**. Since in my case service can contain different amount of power voltage as well as more than one service i.e a bath room may have power service or water supply service !!

Comment: From a modelling perspective, a `House` *has a* `powerSupply`, shared among all rooms, with some fixed(-ish) voltage and maximum power. The MW should be a property of the supply, not the house (although the house wiring may also have some safe maximum).

Comment: well house maximum is what I was thinking from type of wiring

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following arguments:

1. If you are absolutely sure `services` will never change after the `Home` home object has been initialized, then you should choose **Case 1**.
2. If you are not sure that `services` is immutable, or even if you are sure it may be changed, than definitely go for **Case 2**.

The point here is that the choice is based upon how you are going to handle different variables in your business rules. If on variable is never changing than there is no reason to allow so. However if is is interesting that this element may be changed, than this possibility should be given by the `Home` user. A default value as you provided in your code is an excellent approach because most cases may not need to change this variable at all.